# UITableViewCell - distinguish full edit mode and delete row mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewcelleditcontrol

I have `UITableViewController` and after user pres desired button, I have "full edit" mode. To enable this, I call this:

```
@objc func btnEditPressed(sender: UIButton) {
   sender.isSelected = !self.isEditing
   self.setEditing(!self.isEditing, animated: true)

   self.tableView.beginUpdates()
   self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

for each `UITableViewCell`, I have `override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool)` method. In this, I hide some parts of cell in "full edit" mode.

Now, when the user swipe single table row, I show the delete button. However, in this "delete row mode" I dont want to hide any information from the cell. The problem is, that the same `override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool)` for the cell is called as in the first case, leading to hiding cell content.

Is there an easy way, how to solve this, or I have to keep weak reference to `UITableViewController` and check the mode from the cell myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to handle this.

1. Check `showingDeleteConfirmation` in the cell's `setEditing` method.
2. Override `willTransition(to:)` and `didTransition(to:)` in your cell class.

If your table view is not in editing mode and the user performs a swipe-to-delete gesture, then your cell will experience the following sequence:

- `willTransition(to:)` will be called with the mask including the value `UITableViewCell.StateMask.showingDeleteConfirmation`
- `setEditing` will be called with `editing` set to `true`. The cell's `showingDeleteConfirmation` will be equal to `true`
- `didTransition(to:)` will be called with the mask including the value `UITableViewCell.StateMask.showingDeleteConfirmation`

So the simplest solution is to update your cell's `setEditing`:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if showingDeleteConfirmation {
        // User did a swipe-to-delete
    } else {
        // The table view is in full edit mode
    }
}
```